# Как включить антиалиасинг в three.js

Tags: three.js

Как включить антиалиасинг в tree.js, чтобы сгладить линии?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Антиалиасинг запускается так:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
```

Правда говорят не во всех браузерах.

---

Также если вызвать через свойства, то он не запустится так как свойство не является общедоступным.

```
  renderer.antialias = true; // так не работает
```